# Button touch Event

Tags: ios, swift, button, swift3, touch

Please check the below code. 
I made button on mainView. 
But the button doesn't call "thumbsUpButtonPressed" method. 
Please check it!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50)

    button.backgroundColor = .red //.clear
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    button.clipsToBounds = true
    //button.setImage(UIImage(named:"thumbsUp.png"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(thumbsUpButtonPressed), for: .touchDown)

    view.addSubview(button)
}

func thumbsUpButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    print("thumbs up button pressed")
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it prints "thumbs up button pressed", I don't see anything wrong. Do you have more code to show?

Comment: Thank you. But that's all. I made 5 TabViews and it is the code on first TabView. Do you think this code is not working on TabView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass the button in as a parameter you have to specify that in the selector. You do so by adding `(_:)` after the method name.

try:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(thumbsUpButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchDown)
```

If you want it to work with your existing code you would need to change your method to not accept a button as a parameter like so:

```
func thumbsUpButtonPressed() {
    print("thumbs up button pressed")
}
```